# Updating data on a blog

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine

I want to make post editing on my blog. I get data from a form and want to put it into a database. I'm not sure if using setters is the best way, so maybe you can show me better solution?

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
  $formData = $form->getData();

  $post->setTitle($formData->getTitle());
  $post->setText($formData->getText());
  $post->setAuthor($formData->getAuthor());
  $em->flush();

  $this->addFlash(
    'notice',
    'Post updated!'
  );

  return $this->redirectToRoute('admin');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Rather than the title being "Is this the best way ..." you might want to use "Post Editing on my Blog using Symfony2 and Doctrine. Ask the "Is this the best way" question within the body. This might draw more viewers and get you better answers. See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this link http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#updating-an-object could be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `persist()` like so:

```
...
$post->setAuthor($formData->getAuthor());
$em->persist($post);
$em->flush();
...
```

That should do it!